# I would like print the console in JSP

Tags: jsp, console

Every time I run an *action*, I *execute()* a class that writes to the console ( *via System.out.println();* ).

I would like to know if there is a way to print the output of these println inside of my jsp files that will be loaded.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display something in jsp you should (in your action class)

- create a String variable say `myOutput String;`
- create getters and setters for it
- assign value to it in the execute method
- show it in jsp by accessing it's value say `<s:property value="myOutput"/>`

Here is an [example](https://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-property-tag-example/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, this is my code but it doesn't still work 
Java Class
 private String myOutput;
 
 public String getMyOutput() {
  return myOutput;
 }

 public void setMyOutput(String myOutput) {
  this.myOutput = myOutput;
 }
public String execute() {
   
  myOutput = "Heyyyy";
   
  return "SUCCESS";
 }


In JSP file
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
    
<s:property value="myOutput"/>